# Can I use parentheses to group AND/OR operators in Gmail Filters?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

When creating a new email filter in Gmail, can I group AND/OR operators within parentheses to create more advanced conditional rules? For example:

> **Has the words**:
>
> ```
> "Ebay" AND ("Guitar" OR "Drum" OR "Bass")
> ```

The above is supposed to filter mails that contain the exact word *Ebay* **and** one of the exact following: *Guitar*, *Drum* or *Bass*.

Comment: If I recall, `AND` is assumed in your search. Try dropping that and see what you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AI E. is correct. **AND** is assumed, **OR** can be declared. This is according to the [Gmail Help article on Advanced Search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

I recommend reviewing it as there are a lot of ways to improve your Gmail searches using the operators in it.

To address your specific example, you can drop the quotes & the AND operator. Quotes are only needed to search for an exact phrase. 
Ebay (Guitar OR Drum OR Bass) would be the correct formatting for a Gmail search.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if things have changed but AND does not work by default for me - what worked for me was using double quotes to cause the AND operator functionality. So `"Ebay" Drum` would search for Ebay *and* Drum